# Stripe Payments not showing correctly every time

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe into my site, for some reason when the page loads the card details box doesn't load correctly (see image 1 below). However after refreshing the page it seems to show correctly?

**This is how it shows first time:**

[image: This is how it shows first time:]

**And after a reload, it shows correctly like this:**

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="add_card_forms">
      <div class="card_forms_inner">
         <div class="form_group">
          <input id="cardholder-name" type="text" required="" placeholder="Card Holder Name" />
         </div>
        <form id="payment-form" data-secret="<?= $intent->client_secret ?>">
        <div id="card-element"></div>
        <button id="card-button">
        Save Card
        </button>
        </form>

        <form id="autoSubmit" action="../billing-details/savePaymentId.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="payment_id" id="payment_id"/>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
       </div>
```

Console:
[image]

What could be causing this:

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when it doesn't load properly?

Comment: Updated the question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined - STRIPE ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172843/uncaught-referenceerror-stripe-is-not-defined-stripe-error)

Comment: Make sure Stripe.js loads before your JavaScript executes.